# Stuck on a conditional probability question.

Tags: statistics

Conditional density of $Y$ is $g(y│x)=e^{−y−x}$ $(x<y<\infty)$ and marginal density of $X$ is $f(x)=e^{−x}$ (x>0).

1. Marginal density of Y? I integrated $g(y|x)f(x)$ over $y$ from 0 to $\infty$ to get $\frac{1}{2}e^{-y}$.
2. E[Y]? I integrated $yg(y)$ over $x$ from $x$ to $\infty$ to get $\frac{1}{2}(e^{-x}-ye^{-y})$.
3. Var(Y)? I simply need to calculate $E[Y^{2}]−\left[E[Y]\right]^2$.
4. Conditional pdf (X|Y=y)? Is this formula correct $\frac{(g(y│x)f(x))}{(g(y)}$?
5. Conditional expected value of X? Stumped for 5 and 6. Is it just integrating the marginal of X times condition pdf from 4?
6. Conditional variance of X and Y? I know the formula (2nd cond moment minus cond. mean square) but I am having trouble figuring out how to calculate it.